# Packets larger than max_allowed_packet not allowed

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using an import command to import MySQL data. I get an error "Packets larger than max_allowed_packet not allowed", but if I immediately rerun the command, it works. You can see I tried closing and opening the connection between commands, that didn't make a difference. Is there some way around this error?

```
 cmd.Connection = conn;
 conn.Open();

 cmd.CommandText = "SET GLOBAL  max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*1024;";
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 //conn.Close();
 //conn.Open();

 mb.ImportFromFile(file); //Imports a large sql file
 conn.Close();
```

Comment: Show the full code

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: I don't know your server config, but you should be able to just update the maximum allowed packets in one location without having to update it every time in your program.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it though. Why does it give the error, then turn around and work when I try to run the command again?

Comment: Perhaps "closing and opening" the connection doesn't do what you think it does.  Also, there are two different, poorly-coupled `max_allowed_packet` settings.  You're changing the one that restricts what the server will accept.  You also need to be setting the one for your client library, which may restrict what the client will send.  Perhaps on the second run, the client library uses the one from the server.  Hard to guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in MySQL:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

Comment: I forgot to leave my own answer to this, this is the solution I used.